# How to understand the pointer usage in R's .C interface usage

Tags: c, r, pointers

I am a beginner for R extensions. I have problems in understanding the usage of .C interface. Take this code as an example:

```
void cconv(int *l, double *x, int *n, double *s)
     {
       double *y = x + (*n - *l), *z = x + *l, *u = x;
       while ( u < y)
       *s += *u++ * *z++;
     }
```

In this code, I think the arguments should be called as `*l` and `*x` probably because `l` and `x` are defined in R environment and are transferred to the `.C` interface, and please correct it if I am wrong. However, inside the function `cconv`, why `double *y` are defined rather than `double y`, and why pointer and int variable are mixed in defining `*y`. At last, I saw in other codes that if R need call `.C(...)` to return a vector result `s`, then `double *y` is defined as an argument in the C function, but calculated as `s` inside the C function, like:

```
void xfunc(int *l, double *x, double *s){
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0, i < *l, i ++){
        s[i] = x;
     }
}
```

Comment: Many, if not all, experienced R programmers recommend staying away from `.C()` and to use `.Call()`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I think your point is valuable. However, now I prefer I can make clear everything about `.C()` interface.